# Regex Quantifier on Alternatives(vertical bar "|")

Tags: c#, regex, quantifiers

I want to trim a string if it starts and/or ends with foo or bar for example and want to get the inner string in a regex group.
For example

> "fooTestbar" should be "Test",
>  "Test2bar" should be "Test2"
>  and "Test3" should be "Test3".

My current regex is:

```
^(foo|bar)?(.*)(foo|bar)?$
```

but this doesnt work, because I cant apply the Quantifier `?` to the alternative group(`(foo|bar)`). 
**My Code**

```
static string returnMatch(string text){
string pattern = @"^(foo|bar)?(.*)(foo|bar)?$";
return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(text, pattern).Groups[2].Value;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you? Which language/tool are you using?

Comment: Im using .Net`s System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match with C#, it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

`^(?:foo|bar)?(.*?)(?:foo|bar)?$`

You can now match it like this..

```
return Regex.Match(input,"^(?:foo|bar)?(.*?)(?:foo|bar)?$").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Thank you, but this only worked for the beginning foo|bar, not for the and

Comment: Thanks, it worked so for me with a small editing, Regex.Matches doesnt have a replace Parameter.

Comment: Your regex solves this question, I dont need to do Regex.Matches, I can do only Regex.Match and I have the right result in Group 1. Thank you and all others for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to go with

```
(?:^|(?<=^foo)).*?(?=bar$|$)
```

or, if you want to allow `foo` and/or `bar` at the beginning and at the end, then with

```
(?:^|(?<=^foo)|(?<=^bar)).*?(?=foo$|bar$|$)
```

having result in `Groups[0]`

Comment: This replaces only the foo at the beginning, not for example a bar at the beginning and the replacing at the end doesnt work.

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls - I see no such example in your question... I have updated my answer with that alternative.

Comment: Ok, i explained it maybe a little bad, with your updated regex it only replaces foo|bar at the end.

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls - You must have some typo in your code, as my updated answer/solution should work properly. Check your code...